# How to create element of ID's when create a table dynamically

Tags: javascript

Hi guy's i have a problem with creating an element of id's while create a table dynamically. i want make the id's different from one column to the another. i realize that i must use an array for doing that. but i don't know where i must to place that array for the id's.
i want to create the id's of `<input type='text' id='input[J]'` <<< just for example

this is my code for create the table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit-file').on("click", function(e) {
    if ($('#files').val() == "") {
      alert("Anda Harus Memasukkan File Terlebih Dahulu");
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#files').parse({
        config: {
          delimiter: "",
          skipEmptyLines: false,
          complete: displayHTMLTable,
        },
        before: function(file, inputElem) {
          //console.log("Parsing file...", file);
        },
        error: function(err, file) {
          //console.log("ERROR:", err, file);
        },
        complete: function() {
          //console.log("Done with all files");
        }
      });
    }
  });

  function displayHTMLTable(results) {
    var table = "<table id='table_data' class='table table-bordered' width='90%'>";
    var data = results.data;
    var size = -1;
    var check1 = 1;
    var check2 = 100;
    table += "<tbody>";
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      table += "<tr>";
      var row = data[i];
      var cells = row.join(";").split(";");
      if (cells.length < size) continue;
      else if (cells.length > size) size = cells.length;
      if (cells.length < check1 || cells.length > check2) {
        alert('Data Yang Anda Masukkan Salah');
        return false;
      } else {
        for (j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {

          table += "<td>";
          table += cells[j];
          table += "</td>";
        }

        table += "<td><input type='text' name='input1' id='input1' size='2'></td>";
        table += "<td><input type='text' name='input2' id='input2' size='2'></td>";
        table += "<td><input type='text' name='input3' id='input3' size='7'></td>";
        table += "</tr>";

      }
    }
    table += "</tbody>";
    table += "</table>";
    $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the backtick ``(above the tab) then you can use the ${} syntax to gain access to a variable within a string. Below is your code with a `count` variable that is initialized to 1 and then incremented after each use. It can be accessed in any string like this: `here is a string ${count}`

```
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr>";
    var row = data[i];
    var cells = row.join(";").split(";");
    var count = 1;
    if (cells.length < size) continue;
    else if (cells.length > size) size = cells.length;
    if (cells.length < check1 || cells.length > check2) {
      alert('Data Yang Anda Masukkan Salah');
      return false;
    } else {
    for (j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
      table += "<td>";
      table += cells[j];
      table += "</td>";
    }

    table += `<td><input type='text' name='input${count}' id='input${count}' size='2'></td>`;
    count++;
    table += `<td><input type='text' name='input${count}' id='input${count}' size='2'></td>`;
    count++;
    table += `<td><input type='text' name='input${count}' id='input${count}' size='7'></td>`;
    table += "</tr>";

  }
}
```

If you want to do this in a loop then it's even easier. Inside the loop that you're using to create the table make another loop and create each `td` in that loop:

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
  table += `<td><input type='text' name='input${j}' id='input${j}' size='2'></td>`;
}
```

So your table code could use a loop and end up looking like this (I'm not dealing with your data. Just showing you how to make your ids work):

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr>"; 
    for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        table += `<td><input type='text' name='input${j}' id='input${j}' size='2'></td>`;
      }   
   }
   table += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: i try use your method with backtip but make the function get error

Comment: just red flag only ( on editor) and i checked on inspect element in web browser the id's still showing `input`

Comment: Can you put a simplified version on a fiddle to share?

Comment: its running now. 
i just forgot for giving the last part of `;`

but the array is not increment of the the count of table column, but the table row

Comment: i mean called in other function

Comment: You can get it using `getElementById` or using a jQuery selector.

Comment: Oh. I just noticed you're using inputs. You could use a listener to get those. But still not difficult.

Comment: on the function for call that id's or inside the function for create the table

Comment: I made a fiddle for you. The listener is inside the same function that created the table. You can always make the listener call another function if you like. There are ways to do this without jQuery as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/chrissharp80/Lhbzua8n/